# Batch routine avoid exit from other commands

Tags: batch-file, pm2

I have a batch program that executes commands from distinct libraries. The problem is that those libraries finish console automatically when they're executed.

It seems that `pause` command doesn't work because probably those libraries will have they're own `exit` command. I tried with the command `cmd /k` that I found on google, but it doesn't works too.

```
:start
cls

echo.
echo 1) Desc 1
echo 2) Desc 2

set /p option=Enter an option: 

IF "%option%"=="1" (
    rem this is an example of library that exit console after being executed
    pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env development
)
IF "%option%"=="2" (
    pm2 monit
)

pause

goto start
```

The main idea is if there's any method or param to avoid closing the console with those kind of libraries without editing the proper libraries.

Comment: Why not use `choice.exe` for a simple selection and react on the returned errorlevel? There are plenty of examples here on [SO].

Comment: thanks I didn't know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command `call` before the methods will work:

```
:start
cls

echo.
echo 1) Desc 1
echo 2) Desc 2

set /p option=Enter an option: 

IF "%option%"=="1" (
    rem this is an example of library that exit console after being executed
    call pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env development
)
IF "%option%"=="2" (
    call pm2 monit
)

pause

goto start
```

Comment: So `pm2` is a batch file on its own?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I supouse that is the case because that solves the problem